# Watson Profile Variable usage

Tags: ibm-watson

In viewing the Watson Dialog API reference section "[Get profile variables](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/dialog/api/v1/#get-profile)" is states "Get profile variables - Retrieves the profile variables for a given client_id and conversation_id."

However, in the Watson Dialog API Explorer "Get the profile variables for a given cient_ID" there is no attribute shown for specifying a conversation_id. We want to manipulate an independent set of profile variables for every conversation... not just every client_ID. This way, multiple users can converse using the same client_ID (which we are thinking there will be one for every use case) each with their own conversation_id and therefore their own set of profile variables. Is this workable and if so how? If not, how should we handle the need for independent profile variables for each new conversation?

Answer (score 2):

Every user should have their own `client_id`.

A `conversation_id` is only a single session. Multiple users should not use the same `client_id` as that is what the profile values are stored against. `client_id` persists across multiple conversations.

I will get the documentation updated asap.